# Elasticsearch 2.4 post_filter date math

Tags: elasticsearch

When using a `post_filter` with `date math` on an Elasticsearch 2.4 query such as the following:

```
"post_filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "facets.due_date": {
                                "gte": "now+2d\/d",
                                "lte": "now+3d\/d-1s"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
```

The results include documents with dates outside the range by 1 day. The exact same values are used in the aggregations which report the correct counts for the buckets (2 documents for Saturday in this case), however, as mentioned when I apply the above post filter 3 documents are returned [the extra document being for Sunday at 9am]. The dates are arbitrary, I can change them to in a few days and the same thing happens. I'm also on UTC time and have allowed for this in my testing by adding/removing a few hours in the values to bypass any errors raised by timezones.

If I use an actual set of concrete dates it works as expected so my question is, does `post_filter` have a problem / bug with `date math` or is there a way to use `explain` to show me the dates the `post_filter` is sending to the ES server?

Thanks in advance, been banging my head against a brick wall for 3 days on this !!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out for some very strange reason using `lte` on a post filter captures surrounding documents whereas if I use `lt` then it works as expected, I don't have a clue why this is doing this, I can only assume some rounding is taking place when the `post_filter` is applied but it not rounded when the aggregations are calculated!